# The complaints on the view complaints page are not showing up

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I am creating a complaint management system where users can enter their complaints as well as view and edit them and also view other users complaints. On the page where the users can view others complaint, no complaints or data is showing up. What do I do?

This should be showing up :
[image]

But this is what is showing up:

[image]

My models.py:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
   user = models.OneToOneField(User,null= True , blank = True, on_delete= models.CASCADE)
   profile_pic = models.ImageField(default = "msi.jpg", null = True, blank= True, upload_to= 
  'static/profileimages')
  first = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
   last = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
   email = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
   mobile_number = models.IntegerField(null=True)
   location = models.CharField(max_length= 500, null= True)
   postal = models.IntegerField(null=True)

   def __str__(self):
       return self.first

class Complaint(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete= models.CASCADE, null = True, blank=True)
   id = models.AutoField(blank=False, primary_key=True)
   reportnumber = models.CharField(max_length=500 ,null = True, blank= False)
   eventdate = models.DateField(null=True, blank=False)
   event_type = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
   device_problem = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
   manufacturer = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
   product_code = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
   brand_name = models.CharField(max_length = 300, null=True, blank=True)
   exemption = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
   patient_problem = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
   event_text = models.TextField(null=True, blank= True)
   document = models.FileField(upload_to='static/documents', blank=True, null=True)

   def __str__(self):
       return self.reportnumber
```

views.py:

```
class OtherPeoplesComplaints(TemplateView):
   model = Complaint
   form_class = ComplaintForm
   template_name = 'userComplaints.html'
   def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
       context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
       context["complaints"] = self.model.objects.exclude(user = self.request.user)
```

forms.py:

```
class CreateUserForm(UserCreationForm):
   email = forms.EmailField()
   password2 = None
   class Meta:
       model = User
       fields = ['username','first_name', 'last_name','email', 'password1']

class ProfileForm(ModelForm):
   class Meta:
       model = Profile
       fields = '__all__'
       exclude = ['user']
       widgets = {
           'profile_pic': forms.FileInput()
       }

class DateInput(forms.DateInput):
   input_type = 'date'

class ComplaintForm(ModelForm):
   class Meta:
       model = Complaint
       fields = '__all__'
       widgets = {
           'reportnumber': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Report number'}),
           'event_type': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Event type'}),
           'eventdate': DateInput(),
           'device_problem': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Device Problem'}),
           'event_text': forms.Textarea(attrs={'style': 'height: 130px;width:760px'}),
           'manufacturer': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Enter Manufacturer Name'}),
           'product_code': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Enter Product Code'}),
           'brand_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Enter Brand Name'}),
           'exemption': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Enter Exemption'}),
           'patient_problem': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Enter Patient Problem'}),
       }
    
   def clean(self):
       cleaned_data = super(ComplaintForm, self).clean()
       reportnumber = cleaned_data.get('reportnumber')
       event_text = cleaned_data.get('event_text')
       if not reportnumber and not event_text:
           raise forms.ValidationError('You have to write something!')
       return cleaned_data
```

template:

```
 <div class="col-lg middle middle-complaint-con">
        <i class="fas fa-folder-open fa-4x comp-folder-icon"></i>
        <h1 class="all-comp">All Complaints</h1>
        <p class="all-comp-txt">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
        {%for c in complaints %}
        <a href="" style="color:black;">
            <div class="container comp-con-{{forloop.counter0}}">
                {% if request.user.profile.profile_pic.url %}
                <img src={{request.user.profile.profile_pic.url}} class="comp-con-img" alt=""> {% else %}
                <img src="{% static 'profileimages/msi.jpg' %}" class="comp-con-img" alt=""> {% endif %}
                <p class="comp-level-1">{{c.first_name}}</p>
                <p class="comp-title-1">{{c.event_type}}</p>
                <p class="comp-sub-1">{{c.event_text}}</p>
            </div>
        </a> {%endfor%}
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `views.py` for your get context data method... It's actually not returning the context. For example, you have:

```
def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
   context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
   context["complaints"] = self.model.objects.exclude(user = self.request.user)
```

What you should add here is a return statement to return the context you have updated.

```
def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
   context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
   context["complaints"] = self.model.objects.exclude(user = self.request.user)
   return context
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked well! Also could you please tell me what's wrong in my template? caus enow I can see the context and everything but the profile pic I'm getting is the current users pic and not the other users pic

Comment: `{% if request.user.profile.profile_pic.url %}` will pull from the user who is currently making the request to visit the page. What you want is, since you have a user on the **complaint model** you will have to refer to that and not the request user. For example: `{% if c.user.profile.profile_pic.url %}`.